# dafny - puzzling postcondition violation

Tags: graph-algorithm, formal-verification, dafny

so I have a class Vertex and class Edge in an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm that I am trying to complete. it looks like this:

```
class Vertex{
  var id  : int ;
  var wfs : int ;       
  var pred: int ; 

  constructor Init()
  modifies this
  {
  this.wfs :=-1;
  this.pred := -1;
  } 
}

class Edge{
  var source : int;
  var dest: int;
  var weight : int;
}
```

and a Graph class that looks like this:

```
class Graph{
  var vertices : set<Vertex>
  var edges : set<Edge>
  var d : array<int>
}
```

with a bunch of predicates about the graph that are assumed in the running of the algorithm. I am trying to write a method that takes a Vertex as an input and then outputs the current shortest path from source for that vertex, which is stored in d, where the index of d is the "id" of the vertex. The method looks like this:

```
method getVertexwfs(v: Vertex) returns (i: int)
  requires isValid() && hasVertex(v) && v != null
  requires hasVertex(v) ==> 0 <= v.id < d.Length && v in vertices
  ensures  exists s :: 0 <= s < d.Length && d[s] == i 
  {
   var x: int := 0;
    while (x < d.Length)
     invariant  hasVertex(v)
     invariant hasVertex(v) ==> 0 <= v.id < d.Length
     invariant v in vertices && 0 <= v.id < d.Length
        {
            if(v.id == x){ i := d[x]; }
            x := x + 1 ;
        }
   //return i;
  }
```

Where the involved predicates are:

```
predicate isValid()
  reads this, this.edges, this.vertices
  {
  d != null && |vertices| > 0 && |edges| > 0 &&
  d.Length == |vertices| &&
  forall m | m in vertices :: (m != null && 0 <= m.id < d.Length ) &&
  forall m , n | m in vertices && n in vertices && m != n :: (m != null && n 
!= null && m.id != n.id) &&
  forall e | e in edges :: e != null && 0 <= e.source <= e.dest < d.Length &&
  forall e | e in edges :: !exists d | d in edges :: d != e &&  d.source == e.source && d.dest == e.dest
  }
```

and

```
predicate method hasVertex(v: Vertex)
  requires isValid()
  reads this, this.vertices, this.edges
  {
  vertices * {v} == {v}
  }
```

The postcondition for the getVertexwfs() method is violated, despite my insistence in the preconditions for the function that v exists in the Graph and that this implies that the ID for v is an index in the bounds of d.

Am I missing a case where Dafny finds that the return integer is not assigned?

Why is the precondition violated?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getVertexwfs`, I feel like I must be missing something. Why can't the postcondition be `ensures d[v.id] == i`? And why can't the body be `i := d[v.id];`. The loop doesn't seem to do anything interesting; it just unnecessarily searches from 0 to `v.id`.

Also, in `hasVertex`, you can just write `v in vertices`. It's equivalent to what you have.

Finally, in `isValid`, you need to put parentheses around your quantifiers, like this `(forall m | m in vertices :: m != null && 0 <= m.id < d.Length)`. Otherwise, it means that the `forall` continues to the end of the predicate. Also, in modern Dafny, the classnames used as types imply non-nullness automatically. If you never plan to store `null` in the data structure, you can leave the types the same as they are and just delete all the parts of `isValid` that talk about not being `null`.

If I make these changes, the program verifies.